# Public URL access from kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, proxy

We have a huge cluster.

And whenever we want the deployment to communicate to the public URL’s (like google etc..from within the pods)

We will have to open up proxy for all the nodes in the cluster (as we are behind a proxy)

Whenever we add a new node we need to make sure all of the rules are working as the `kubernetes` pods can spin anywhere in the cluster…

Can this requirement be achieved using any of the network policies? (Im pretty new to this concept and I guess there can be some `egress` rules written)

Comment: You can do that, but by default, all nodes in AKS should be able to access the Internet, if in your scenario this is not possible, you need to apply some Egress service, there are many available, a lot of people use strategies like Stio, etc. but again, I think that there's a problem in your network topology, you can use other techniques in the network level as well.

In that scenario, I'm pretty sure you will end-up using advanced network feature in K8s, please check this link with a list of net providers:
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/networking/

Comment: So by default we cant access internet from our nodes..So in that case network policies will not work?Do we definetely need a egress service ?Any suggestions on which is widely used for this type of problems?

Comment: What kind of proxy are you taking about?

Comment: If you have a firewall in your network ruling all inbound/outbound connections I don't see a need to control that using Network Policy inside your cluster to avoid access to external internet resources. Yet you should have a network policy to secure your internal traffic between pods and namespaces.
This is also known as North/South traffic (Firewall)